# How to delete entire row if a cell is not numeric in VBA? My code deletes everything

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, row, numeric

I would like to delete entire row if a cell within Column A is not numeric. Plenty of material online, but for some reason my code deletes all numeric and non-numeric data

Any thoughts? 
Thanks

```
Sub Test_If_Numeric()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1

        If Not IsNumeric(i) > 0 Then

            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Maybe I have to set a range? Maybe i As Long does not suffice; any thoughts how to do that or a solution? :)

Comment: may  use `if IsNumeric(cells(i,"A").value) then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Not IsNumeric(i) > 0` statement will always be `True` because:

1. `i` is a number between `LastRow` to `1`, meaning that `IsNumeric(i)` always returns `True`
2. `True > 0` always returns `False` (comparing non-converted boolean with a true number always returns `False`)
3. `Not False` always returns `True`

In order to delete all non-numeric rows, try replacing `If Not IsNumeric(i) > 0 Then` with `If Not IsNumeric(Range("A" & i).Value) Then`

Comment: No problem at all, hope the explanation is clear & everything works for you. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

While you can iterate through a range, another way would be to delete all non-numeric rows at once. Hereby a little example with some sample data in column A:A

[image]

Running code that makes use of `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)`:

```
Sub DelNonNumeric()

Dim Rng As Range
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change sheetname accordingly
    Set Rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
    Rng.Rows.EntireRow.Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Resulting in:

[image]